# How do I swap the left hand and right hand sides of a C/C++ assignment statement in gvim?

Tags: java, c++, python, vim, variable-assignment

To be honest, I actually have a solution for this, but Google search finds so many great tips for me from this site, that I had to contribute something back. Here is what I came up with. For a single line:

> s/^\(\s\+\)\(.*\) = \(.*\);/\1\3 = \2;/

For multiple lines starting at the current line, add `.,.+<line count>`.  For example:

> .,.+28s/^\(\s\+\)\(.*\) = \(.*\);/\1\3 = \2;/

will substitute on the current line and the following 28 lines.  This should also work for Java and Perl.  For Python, omit the ending semicolon from the pattern and substitution (unless you're the sort who uses the optional semicolon).

After typing all that, I find I do have a question.  Is there a way to simplify it so I don't have so many escape characters?

Comment: I don't think I ever swapped the lhs and rhs of an assignment...

Comment: I am writing some unit tests for some (very inelegant) C code, and need to preserve and restore globals.  After writing the preserve function, the restore function is much easier to write by swapping lhs and rhs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use 'very magic': add `\v` to the expression. See `:help magic`. Basically, it mean that all non-alphanumeric characters have special (i.e. regular expression operator meanings) *unless* escaped, which means that they do not need to be escaped in your usage above.

Answer (score 1):

Using \v at the start of your regex can help make it more readable. \v means "very magic", that all characters have are special except those in the sets '0'-'9', 'a'-'z', 'A'-'Z' and '_'.

So your first example could be converted like so:

```
s/\v^(\s+)(.*) \= (.*)\;/\1\3 = \2\;/
```

The `=` and the `;` now need to be escaped to identify them as literals but all the other high-ASCII chars don't.

Comment: What do = and ; mean in regular expressions?  This works (at least in my case) if I escape the = but not the ;

Comment: @HenryLongmore: `=` is like `?`; see `:help /\=` or more generally `:help pattern-overview`. I think `;` is covered under `:help //;`